# Binding entities of a List<T> to DataGrid columns in a dynamically created grid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

Although there are many similar questions, I haven't found the answer that really works for me.

So, in my data, I have objects that contain a list element called BackupPaths. I have an accessor called GetBackupPaths that returns such a list:

```
public List<EMSBackupPath> GetBackupPaths
{
    get {return BackupPaths;}
}
```

In my Grid builder I dynamically add columns based upon the number of backup paths. Each row has the same number and name of element so the columns should be a consistent set for all rows.

My binding clause is:

```
string binding1_string = "GetBackupPaths[" + Headers[i].Index.ToString() + "].TheBackupLevel";
```

Which translates to

```
GetBackupPaths[0].TheBackupLevel
GetBackupPaths[1].TheBackupLevel
GetBackupPaths[2].TheBackupLevel
...
```

My binding looks like this:

```
Binding ValueBinding = new Binding(binding1_string);
```

My question is, can a binding return a list element in the manner I have coded it?

It seems to work fine, but when scrolling the grid up and down things get out of order and the wrong data gets shown against the (sorted) rows of the supplying object.
Is there a "approved" method for returning an element of a list in a binding?
TIA.

Comment: See [PropertyPath for Objects in Data Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451(v=vs.100).aspx#databinding_s). `GetBackupPaths[0].TheBackupLevel` is a valid path.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and link to the appropriate info in the MSDN help files. Seems I have a different issue then, that may be indexing related, at least I know the binding should be good.